# This post does not meet our quality standards

Tags: support, quality-filter

Title:

> read multiple wav files in matlab

Body:

> I want read multiple wav files one by one in one folder. I have 50 wav files.Write 50 wavread function should not be the solution. I want also take file name as string. How can i do that?

Answer (score 5):

This would of been instantly met with multiple comments asking "what have you tried?".

StackOverflow is not a tutorial service, it is a Q&A service for people who have already written up some code and are now faced with an issue they can't resolve.

A question should only be posted after considerable effort has been put into discovering the answer.

I took the first line of your question and pasted it in Google, it came back with this: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/5115

Now, I don't know Matlab but that sure looks to me like it answers your question.

See this [meta post for more info on what is required of you.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know the specific criteria for what triggered the message, but:

- **The body is short.**  Some good questions can be short, but more often than not, they aren't.
- **There are grammatical errors.**  We appreciate the difficulty in communicating in a second language, but properly written questions are more comprehensible, and therefore better.
- **There's no code, or any indication of effort on your part.**  The more specific your question, and the more effort you've already gone through that you can talk about in the question, the better.  The community will only travel so far to meet you where you are.